# how to write to EMR's HDFS from outside the VPC

Tags: hadoop, emr, amazon-emr, amazon-vpc, vpc

I'm trying to write to HDFS on EMR from an external client that's outside the VPC. The following error is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/sdc/temperature-humidity/2018-03-22-04/_tmp_sdc-5bb89fd7-1b80-11e8-95f0-251c07cb2860_0 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 2 datanode(s) running and 2 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2561)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:790)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:459)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor212.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:185)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:558)
```

The job creates empty files on hdfs:

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/sdc/temperature-humidity
drwxr-xr-x   - sdc sdc          0 2018-03-22 15:06 /user/sdc/temperature-humidity/2018-03-22-15
-rw-r--r--   3 sdc sdc          0 2018-03-22 15:04 /user/sdc/temperature-humidity/2018-03-22-15/sdc-5bb89fd7-1b80-11e8-95f0-251c07cb2860_343b936c-e72f-4ba0-8dd3-6c2ccf819cd8
```

I notice that the datanodes are using internal names and private IP's:

```
hdfs$ hdfs dfsadmin -report | grep -i name
Name: 172.31.11.201:50010 (ip-172-31-11-201.us-east-2.compute.internal)
Hostname: ip-172-31-11-201.us-east-2.compute.internal
Name: 172.31.3.174:50010 (ip-172-31-3-174.us-east-2.compute.internal)
Hostname: ip-172-31-3-174.us-east-2.compute.internal
```

I suspect that the client can talk to the namenode because it has a public DNS. It creates the file entry in the namespace, but then fails to write the data to the datanodes because the the namenode tells the client to write to their internal names which aren't resolvable outside the VPC, e.g.

[image: EMR client write]

Q) how can I configure my EMR and/or client so it can write to the EMR HDFS from ouside the VPC?

Comment: Change the hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml files to use an external address. Open the RPC, HTTP, and IPC ports of HDFS, then your cluster would be wide open to the internet... It's suggested that you use a "bastion host" instead that you SSH into, then perform HDFS operations from. EMR also has Hue that you can external expose rather than all the datanodes directly. Or WebHDFS is another option

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. I'll try putting the external address in hdfs/core-site.xml. Good idea.

Comment: You can try using custom DNS server & Custom hostnames in DHCP options of your EMR VPC. Then load your DNS server with all forward and reverse look ups for all VPC's IP range in zone files.

Comment: @AlexWoolford Did you solve this issue? Did the core-site and hdfs-site change work? I am having this exact issue.

Comment: @wolfcall perhaps you could use S3 instead of HDFS in EMR. You can certainly write to an S3 bucket from outside the VPC, and EMR can read directly from S3.

Comment: @AlexWoolford is that how you handled your issue?